# TYPO3 how remove file with references

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 7.6.18.

I have MyVendor\Extension\Domain\Model\FileReference Object

So tell me please how to delete this file? I need delete file, and rows from sys_file and sys_file_reference tables. Help me please, anybody!

Comment: you also want to delete assigned files to record ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API to delete the file. All references will be cleaned automatically.

```
$file->getStorage()->deleteFile($file);
```

Comment: As `getStorage` is a method and not a property, the curly braces are missing :) But yes, this works, thanks!

Comment: Ah, yes you are right. It's a method and no property

Comment: Also the `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\AbstractFile` has a delete Method to directly do what you've mentioned:
```/**
 * Deletes this file from its storage. This also means that this object becomes useless.
 *
 * @return bool TRUE if deletion succeeded
 */
public function delete()
{
    // The storage will mark this file as deleted
    return $this->getStorage()->deleteFile($this);
}```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to remove the file from all records where it is used, then you can delete the file. The info action on the file will give you a list of all usages.

Comment: That's only if you use the action in the filelist. If you use the API directly there is no check and the file gets deleted + all sys_file_references get removed

Comment: Well, it is very questionable if you really want to do this.